# Validating a model based on the value set for a separate model

Tags: python, django, django-models, modelform, django-validation

##### **Background**

I am creating an E-commerce application that allows users to submit bids on any active item listings – where `Bid` & `Listing` are distinct Django models in **`models.py`** (*below*).

For each new bid, the **bid amount** (`Bid.amount`) is set via a Model Form. If the bid amount is greater than the **current bid** (`Listing.current_bid`), then:

1. The `Bid` is considered valid and the object is saved.
2. `Listing.current_bid` is updated to equal the new `Bid.amount`.

---

##### **Issue**

Currently, my solution (*see* **`views.py`** *below*) achieves the desired result – it successfully validates and updates each new bid using a conditional concatenated with the call to `is_valid()`:

```
if new_bid_form.is_valid() and new_bid_form.cleaned_data["current_bid"] > previous_bid:
```

However, even though this design works, it feels "*hackish*", because the validation logic does not occur within the model. Therefore, the condition is not implicitly checked on the call to `clean()`, and I can foresee that causing issues going forward. Instead, I want to implement the validation logic within the model so that its called with Django's built-in validation and will raise a `ValidationError`.

---

##### **Question**

1. Am I correct in saying that my current "validation" solution is poorly designed?
2. If so, how can I validate within the `Bid` model, that the value entered into the form for `Bid.amount` is greater than `Listing.current_bid`? (*See Solution Attempts below*)

---

#### models.py

**`Listing Model`**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usernames")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    starting_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    current_bid = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    image = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

**`Bid Model`**

```
 class Bid(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owners")
        listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
        amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
```

---

#### **views.py**

**`listing() Function`**: Defines a view for each listing & implements a `ModelForm` to submit bids.

```
def listing(request, listing_id):
    class NewBidForm(ModelForm):
        template_name = "auctions/form_template.html"
        class Meta:
            model = Bid
            fields = ["amount"]
            widgets = {
                "amount":forms.NumberInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Submit an offer greater than the current listing price"})
            }
            labels = {
                "amount":_("Submit an Offer:")
            }
    
    # Get the current bid for the current listing
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    current_bid = listing.current_bid

    # If the submitted form data is valid, update & save new bid
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_bid_form = NewBidForm(request.POST)
        if new_bid_form.is_valid() and new_bid_form.cleaned_data["amount"] > current_bid:
            new_bid_form.instance.amount = new_bid_form.cleaned_data["amount"]
            new_bid_form.instance.owner = request.user
            new_bid_form.instance.listing = listing
            new_bid_form.save()

            # Set the listing's current bid to the new bid amount
            listing.current_bid = new_bid_form.instance.amount
            listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[listing_id]))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "listing": listing,
                "form": new_bid_form,
                "message": messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Bid must be greater than the current highest bid."),
            })
```

---

##### Solution Attempts

So far, I've been unable to find a similar example that provided any hints at a solution that I could iterate on. From the Django documentation, it seems **overriding the `clean()` method** might *potentially* be a way to achieve this, but I have not found a way to do this when one (*unsaved*) model instance, depends on an instance of another distinct model.

I attempted a solution that used the `clean()` method below in my `Bid` model:

```
def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.amount < self.listing.current_bid:
            raise ValidationError("Bid must be greater than the previous current bid")
```

However, this returned an error, which I believe is because the new `Bid` is not yet saved, thus does not have a reference to `.listing`:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /listing/1. Bid has no listing.
```

Any insight would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that might have a similar issue, I was able to find a solution (which was staring me in the face) by overriding the `clean()` method as I had guessed.

The error was raised because the `Bid` object did not yet have a reference to `Listing` at the time the overridden `clean()` method was being invoked.

Therefore, by instantiating the `Bid` with a reference to the listing object, I was able to solve the issue:

```
def listing(request, listing_id):
    class NewBidForm(ModelForm):
        template_name = "auctions/form_template.html"
        class Meta:
            model = Bid
            fields = ["amount"]
            widgets = {
                "amount":forms.NumberInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Submit an offer greater than the current listing price"})
            }
            labels = {
                "amount":_("Submit an Offer:")
            }
    
    # Get the current listing to bid on.
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)

    # Validate that the new bid is greater than the current highest bid.
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_bid_form = NewBidForm(request.POST, instance=Bid(listing=listing))
        if new_bid_form.is_valid():
            new_bid_form.instance.amount = new_bid_form.cleaned_data["amount"]
            new_bid_form.instance.owner = request.user
            new_bid_form.save()

            # Set the listing's current bid to the new bid amount.
            listing.current_bid = new_bid_form.instance.amount
            listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[listing_id]))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "listing": listing,
                "form": new_bid_form,
            })
```

For reference, a slight revision to the `clean()` method in the `Bid` model:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owners")
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.amount <= self.listing.current_bid:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Unable to place new bid! Please enter a minimum bid of at least $%(value)s!"), 
                params={"value":f"{float(self.listing.current_bid) + 1.0:.2f}"})
```